# Angular 2 bug with setInterval?

Tags: angular, setinterval

I am trying to implement a div that automatically scrolls to the bottom, unless it had been scrolled by the user.
My Html :

```
<ul id='logWrap' class='logWrap' (scroll)="onLogScroll()">
       ...  
</ul>
```

the relevant code in my component :

```
ngOnInit(){
    setInterval(() => { this.updateScroll() }, 3000);
  }

  updateScroll(){
    var element = document.getElementById("logWrap");
    if(element && !this.scrolled){
      element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
    }
  }

  onLogScroll(){
    this.scrolled = true;
  }
```

onLogScroll gets called correctly and sets this.scrolled to true. However, it is somehow set back to false by updateScroll and "element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;" is executed no matter what, at every pass in the function.

"this.scrolled" is touched nowhere else in the code. I must be missing something simple.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't show any code that could possibly set 'scrolled' to false, it has to be somewhere, right?

Comment: The only code that sets it to false is in the variable declaration in the component :  scrolled:boolean= false;  This is why I believe this may be a bug with Angular 2.